# What is the mental picture to have when something is required/imported in JS?

Tags: javascript, import, require

I'm not sure how to think about it, if 1 file requires or imports another, is it correct to just think of it as the required code being copied pasted into the file that required it? How does it work when `foo.js` requires `bar.js` but they both require react? Does it react get copied twice?

Comment: Which import are you referring to? commonjs, AMD or es6 Harmony? Here is a [comparison of commonjs and harmony](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_in-es6-imports-are-live-read-only-views-on-exported-values)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like webpack where all of your code is bundled up into a single file, you can think of it like this: both of your bar.js and foo.js code will be in the same file as well as react, so no code/file will be copied more than once.